# How can I open a Markdown file?

Tags: markdown

I have a Markdown file, and I want to open it with the formatting. I tried using a web browser, but it just gave me plain text. I also added two Chrome extensions, but it still just gave me some plain text.

Links to those extensions:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview-plus/febilkbfcbhebfnokafefeacimjdckgl
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk
https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/markdown-here/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Atom. It can be downloaded at https://www.atom.io. Atom includes a package to preview Markdown files. It can be activated by using `Ctrl+Shift+M`.

Source: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/writing-in-atom/

Answer (score 4):

I use Visual Studio Code to edit and view markdown.
You can edit markdown just like any other text file.

To see the formatted version, just right click the tab and select "Open Preview."

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown

Answer (score 3):

If you use this website [here](https://stackedit.io/)! and click start writing at the top you can paste your markdown on the left and see a preview of how it looks on the right. Also, markdown is just a text file so if you open it using anything it will still be a textfile; the link I suggested shows you the text file on the left and shows you a markdown preview.
You would add a link like this:
       "[the test you want people to see](your http link)"

Answer (score 1):

You might like [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/). It has a lot of features so it might be daunting but you don't have to use all of them. It primarily uses Markdown files and so you can use your Markdown files with it and they should mostly work. I don't use it (I use Visual Studio Code like Merkle Groot) so I don't know if it will handle inline html/css/js properly but it's worth checking out.

Comment: +1 for Obsidian, it is a great markdown editor. It also offers visualization features to build mind maps with your files (based on links between them).